# In React, is it a good practise to return null if props is empty

Tags: reactjs, redux

Given my code:

```
class Example extends Components {
  constructor(props) {
     super(props)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
     //fetch data
  }

  render() {
     const {obj} = this.props;
     if(R.isEmpty(obj)) {
        return null;
     }

     return (<div>{obj.name}</div>)
  }
}
```

the `obj` is retrieved from server. so for the initial render, `obj` is empty. If I don't return null, `obj.name` would report error

so is it a good practise to return `null` before I get response from server? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is the proper way. If don't want to `render` anything `return null`.

One more thing if you want to wait for `response` and hold the `rendering` until that, you can `return` this also:

```
if(R.isEmpty(obj)) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>
}
```

By this way user will come to know that something is going on, some kind of data is being fetch from `server`, this is more intuitive i think.

Comment: Good answer, I would also add a reference to the doc: [Preventing Component from Rendering](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/conditional-rendering.html#preventing-component-from-rendering)

Comment: thanks, feeling awesome, this part is going to `react doc` :)

Answer (score 0):

> so is it a good practice to return null before I get a response from
>   the server?

It is ok to do it but also depends on a situation.
For example in some case, you can avoid rendering the component at all like this:

```
class ParentComp extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {!R.isEmpty(obj) && <Example obj={obj}/>}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: No this is not the same component, this is the parent component. The win here is that you can avoid rendering component completely. This matters sometimes because for example, you may have some logic in `incomponentWillReceiveProps` and there is no point of running it.